# How can I create "pulsing" animation - CSS animation timing offset subject

Tags: css, animation, timing

I need to create "pulsing" animation. But animation with opacity changing moving in time during odd iterations. First iteration second gradient show in time, but next iteration - opacity-animation offset.Help please!
Code :

```css
.gradient {
    height: 292px;
    width: 260px;
    margin-left: 76px;
    margin-top: 61px;
    left: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 1;
}

.gradient_main {
    background: #1000af;
    background: linear-gradient(135deg, #1201b0, #87078b, #ff0505, #ff8700, #f9c700);
    background-size: 400% 100%;
    opacity:1;
    -webkit-animation: bannerGradientMain 10s infinite linear alternate;
}

.gradient_main2 {
    background: #1000af;
    background: linear-gradient(135deg, #87078b, #ff0505, #ff8700, #f9c700, #98AB22, #00681b);
    background-size: 400% 100%;
    background-position: left center;
    opacity:0;
    -webkit-animation: bannerGradientMain2 10s infinite linear alternate;
}


/*FIRST GRADIENT ANIMATION*/

@keyframes bannerGradientMain {
    0% {
        background-position: 0% 0%;  
       
    }
    47%{
        background-position: 100% 0%;         
    }

    52%{ 
        background-position: 100% 0%;        
    }

    100% {
        background-position: 0% 0%;
        
    }
}

/*SECOND GRADIENT ANIMATION*/

@keyframes bannerGradientMain2 {
    0% {
        background-position: 0% 0%;
        opacity: 0;
    }
    47% {
        background-position: 100% 0%;
        opacity: 0;
    }

    52% {
        background-position: 100% 0%;
        opacity: 1;
    }
    97%{
        opacity:1; 
    }
    100% {
        background-position: 0% 0%;
        opacity: 0;
    }
}
```

```html
    <div>
        <div class="gradient gradient_main"></div>
        <div class="gradient gradient_main2"></div>

    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery to achieve this:

```
$(document).bind('click', function() {  
    var p = $(".gradient_main");    
    for(var i=0; i<3; i++) {
       p.animate({opacity: 0.2}, 100, 'linear').animate({opacity: 1}, 100,'linear');
    }
});
```

[Here](https://jsfiddle.net/rxdLqe69/) is a working fiddle. Click on the box to see pulsation. Check [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3308302/jquery-pulsating-text) for more

Comment: but timing whatever is bad(

Comment: You can control the timing by changing the second parameter (100). Check the [API](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) for more about how to configure.